# Does MTM of a Bond include its accrued interest?

Tags: financial-literacy, bonds

I understand that the MTM of a bond refers to Mark to Market value. I am trying to understand whether such price also includes accrued interest if any. I tried searching a lot in google, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: To my knowledge, bonds are not typically marked-to-market. What is the context? Where are you seeing this happen?

Comment: @DStanley illiquid bonds get market to market for various reasons, usually for things like calculating VAR and CVAR on an intraday basis. I calculate VAR for my own holdings and am showing my father how to do the same for his just to head off the comment that that isn't a personal finance use.

Answer (score 1):

Marking something to market generally means assigning the current liquidation value.

If you mark a bond to market then you include accrued interest since if you sell it you will receive funds based on the dirty price.

A more thorough walkthrough of a bond trader's daily PnL. On day zero his bond is valued at a dirty price of (100+1) = 101. On day one the clean price rises by 0.5 and the accrued increase by 0.02 so the dirty price is now (100.5 + 1.02) = 101.52, i.e. the trader has gained 0.52. But he is liable for funding costs. His treasury department charges him the equivalent of 0.015 for the repo cost, so overall his daily PnL is 0.505, which is close to the clean price difference.

Answer (score 1):

@Attack68 is correct. To clarify a point in your question that the answer did not make explicit, "mark to market" and "price" are not the same thing.

Marking a bond to market is the act of assigning a price to the bond. Many bonds (e.g. corporate bonds) do not enjoy real-time screen pricing from an authoritative source like an exchange, so they must be "marked" by a human or by a price matrix that uses human input.

By market convention, those prices typically *exclude* accrued interest ("clean" price). That is because clean prices are easier to compare from one day to the next, whereas including accrued interest ("dirty" price) means that one has to do an extra calculation to see how much a bond's price has moved in the market. As @Attack68 says, it is the dirty price that matters in marking a long or short position to market. But dirty and clean prices are just accounting identities.

Comment: thanks a lot. Also, the "Fair Value" would include accrued interest, right?

Comment: You would have to give an example. As explained, market convention for quoting bond *prices* is to use clean prices.